# How to substitute some text in a existing PDF file while using includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

I have a existing PDF, and it is included into my document through `\includepdf` in package `pdfpages`, and I'm curious that can some text in the PDF file be substituted by some else?

For example, I have `foo.pdf` with contents

```
foo foo1 foo2
```

and it's included in `bar.tex`

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{foo.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Can I add some directives in `bar.tex`, substituting `foo1` in `foo.pdf` with `bar1`, making `bar.pdf` like this

```
foo bar1 foo2
```

As I know, package `PSfrag` can edit text in EPS file.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. You'll need a tool like `qpdf`.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Please make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

pdfTeX, *etc.*, cannot edit the content of PDFs: they only copy material from the source PDF files into the output PDF. As such, if you want to do more complex modifications you will need to use a third-part tool such as [`qpdf`](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: How about `pdftk`? Can it be used for this question?

Comment: @PSTikZ No, not in this case. The question seems to be about editing the text of a PDF, which `pdftk` can't do. If it's just a question of picking specific pages then you don't even need an external tool.